# Jsoup css selector "not", not return anything

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to ignore an item and not parse it on Jsoup
But css selector "not", not working !!
I don't understand what is wrong ??

my code:

```
 MangaList list = new MangaList();
    Document document = getPage("https://3asq.org/");
    MangaInfo manga;
    for (Element o : document.select("div.page-item-detail:not(.item-thumb#manga-item-5520)")) {
        manga = new MangaInfo();
        manga.name = o.select("h3").first().select("a").last().text();           
        manga.path = o.select("a").first().attr("href");
        try {
            manga.preview = o.select("img").first().attr("src");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            manga.preview = "";
        }
       
   
        list.add(manga);
    }
    return list;
```

html code:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 badge-pos-1">
        <div class="page-item-detail manga">
                            <div id="manga-item-5520" class="item-thumb hover-details c-image-hover" data-post-id="5520">
                                            <a href="https://3asq.org/manga/gosu/" title="Gosu">
                            <img width="110" height="150"  src="https://3asq.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/IMG_4497-110x150.jpg" srcset="https://3asq.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/IMG_4497-110x150.jpg 110w, https://3asq.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/IMG_4497-175x238.jpg 175w" sizes="(max-width: 110px) 100vw, 110px" class="img-responsive" style=""  alt="IMG_4497"/>                                                           </a>
                                        </div>
            <div class="item-summary">
                <div class="post-title font-title">
                    <h3 class="h5">
                                                        <a href="https://www.noal0.tk/" target="_blank"><span class="manga-title-badges custom noal-manga">Noal-Manga</span></a>                                                        <a href="https://3asq.org/manga/gosu/">Gosu</a>
                    </h3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I debug your code and extract the HTML for:

`System.out.println(document.select("div.page-item-detail").get(0))` (hint use the expression evaluator in IntelliJ IDEA (`Alt`+`F8` - for in-session, real-time debugging)

I get:

```html
<div class="page-item-detail manga"> 
 <div id="manga-item-2003" class="item-thumb hover-details c-image-hover" data-post-id="2003"> 
  <a href="http...
  ...
  </div> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

It looks like you want to extract the next `div` tag down with `class` containing `item-thumb` ... but only if the id isn't `manga-item-5520`.

So here's what I did to remove that one item

```java
document.select("div.page-item-detail div[class*=item-thumb][id!=manga-item-5520]")
```

Result size: 19

With the element included:

```java
document.select("div.page-item-detail div[class*=item-thumb]")
```

Result size: 20

You can also try the following if you want to remain based at the outer `div` tag rather than the inner `div` tag.

```java
document.select("div.page-item-detail:has(div[class*=item-thumb][id!=manga-item-5520])")
```